# How to retrieve region code for Facebook Marketing API

Tags: facebook

I'm creating a campaign through `Facebook Marketing API` and need to specify `region codes`. How can I easily find these codes?

I'm planning on hard-coding these `region codes`, so I'm looking for a quick solution, like manually planning a Facebook ad and retrieving these codes from the URL or from a `post/get` action. Any hacks you know off?

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/targeting-search/v2.9

Comment: @CBroe I know, but that means I need to develop to get a few simple IDs...

Comment: Use Graph API Explorer, and extract the list from there ...?

Comment: @CBroe Isn't Grap API different from Facebook Marketing API?

Comment: You can use GAE to make requests to any API endpoint that you would access via `https://graph.facebook.com/...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering my own question :)

`Region codes` can be retrieved using Facebook Graph Explorer as follows:

[search?type=adgeolocation&location_types=region&country_code=US](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/?method=GET&path=search%3Ftype%3Dadgeolocation%26location_types%3Dregion%26country_code%3DUS&version=v2.9)